# Recovered bitcoin public keys do not verify the signature

Tags: transactions, public-key, signature

I need to recover public keys on the bitcoin chain for a project, my current flow is like this:

Get hash + signature from bigquery -> Use nodeJS secp256k1 module (native bindings) to import signature from DER signature -> recover public key from signature and hash-> verify public key against signature and hash.

The problem is, only about half of the public keys verify. Initially I thought it's either y-coordinate issues or issues with the recid number, but as far as I can tell, neither is the case.

Oddities that I have found:
No matter whether I put 0 or 1 as recid, either both (different) recovered public keys verify, or neither do.
DER Signatures with a 144 hex length (72 bytes) never have their recovered public keys verify, while shorter signatures become increasingly more likely to correctly verify.

My code:

```
    var uintsig = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(textasm, 'hex'));
    var uinthash = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(texthash, 'hex'));
    var sig = secp256k1.signatureImport(uintsig)

    var pubk = secp256k1.ecdsaRecover(sig, 1, uinthash)
    var ver = secp256k1.ecdsaVerify(sig, uinthash, pubk)
```

Sample data, one fails one goes correctly:

```
Does not verify:
{
  sig: '3045022074e221c10f7d1baeadc8f4f22b6c738997bf5864027787ac337b18ab3ad89488022100adcefaf4182096e06bd3e57756e4029dfd598c755a0885499a178043d1ef6766',
  hash: '6aa7a48970a9f1609583701848b30ec622c1efc7eb11c57652254c4c44637475'
}
--------
Does verify:
{
  sig: '30440220773971d9aeb4e02bf41e978621a5dc110e1f91f1b7c773b774d37dea98a89074022061000945e5852ed4b9cc17dc39f7ddaa68c235b1f826fc68fcad913662b59a68',
  hash: '642a77be5a9203209b1136a5df685a645fddd3a81785b19a7d3910a2d5d77955'
}
```